# How to run dot net console app using Windows task scheduler?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I created my first dot net console app (C# and dot net framework) using Visual studio in a server. Now I need to move the app to a computer without visual studio and have to schedule to run the app in Windows task scheduler but have no clue what to google. Can anyone please guide me?
I am familiar with creating PowerShell scripts and running the file using Task Scheduler. It was simple to run Powershell script because I choose powershell program in task scheduler and point to single file I created. However here in .net app there are so many files and not sure which program to use to run in Task scheduler.
Also before I setup schedule task is it possible to run the app in command prompt or Visual Studio Code?
Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Just copy the whole bin\Release folder. You can run the .exe file there either by doubleclicking it or from the task scheduler.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thank you for quick response. I double clicked exe file in FirstProgram/bin/Debug/firstprogram.exe. it opens in commnad prompt nd immedately closes. Is there a way to open this in Visual Studio Code to test it my PC?

Comment: You can open a cmd yourself and then execute your file from there, that way the cmd will stay open. Another way is to add something like "Console.ReadKey()", because the cmd will then wait for any input and won't close until you press any key. To get the final files usually you have to "publish" your project, so right click the console project and choose publish ([more info here](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0)). The resulting files can then be copied to destination PC, choose the .exe to start it (also in task scheduler)

Comment: Thank you @DanielD That was very Helpful. I got it done following your guidance :)